# How add multiple entity class in single JPARepository in springboot application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, jparepository

@Repository
public interface ticketsDao extends JpaRepository<owners, Object>

For every entity class, I need to create the Dao. How I use multiple entity class in single Dao.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible as you can only query on one entity and there can be only one Entity for a repository

You can use Joins in your queries if you want to query from other tables. However, with JpaRepository you can only extend with one at a time.